# Short circuit protection of lithium pouch cells in parallel

Tags: lithium-ion, fuses, batteries

I want to put together a battery pack with 2 or 3 lithium pouch cells (for example [SLPB11543140H5](http://kokam.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/SLPB-Cell-Brochure.pdf)) in parallel, and a few more in series. Of course they have to have some kind of short circuit protection. 
In the pdf linked above, the manufacturer mentions a tab fuse. After asking the manufacturer directly about it, this seems to be just a removeable tab, not a fuse.

What would be the right strategy to do this?

With cylindrical cells most people (TESLA for example) use a thin wire which is welded directly on to the cell and the busbar which then acts as a fuse. However this is not possible with the tabs of pouch cells.

Is there a commmon way to achieve this?

Comment: The cells in parallel should not share a current pathway with the cells in series, they should be independent. By the way the first statement is written, it sounds like you want to put something like 3 cells in parallel with something like 2 cells in series

Comment: "Of course they have to have some kind of short circuit protection" - why?

Comment: I thought it is necessary, in case one cell fails. So that it´s not possible for one cell to create a short circuit over the other cells in parallel.
"A few more cells in series" actually was an understatement, because I wanted the question to focus on the cells in parallel. The whole battery pack will have 144 cells in series for a total voltage of about 605V and there will be a main fuse where all curent has to go through.